# Extracting spectral values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spot5, geomatica

I'm busy working on a project and I have orthorectified and atmospherically corrected SPOT5 images. We now need to create a point shapefile and then extract the spectral value of the cell at that point.

I am struggling with extracting spectral values. We are using PCI geomatica and/or ArcGIS in our processing. Is there a way of doing this on either one of the softwares?

Comment: This thread may start you off with some ideas: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123475/fit-point-with-raster-data-figure-out-those-points-belong-to-and-add-column-and/123478#123478

Answer (score 1):

With ArcGIS you can use the "Extract Multi Values to Points" (http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000002s000000.htm). In my opinion this is the most straightforward solution.

Alternatively, you can use geomatica's "VIMAGE" function. More details http://www.pcigeomatics.com/geomatica-help/references/pcifunction_r/python/p_vimage.html